# how can I display an ad and its comments in Laravel

Tags: laravel, comments

I facing problem while I want to display my ad and its comments in page.blade only

My page ***show.blade.php*** which contains the object and the description of the *ad* an I want to display even the comments in this page also

```
   <strong> Object:</strong>                 {{$user->object}}<br>    
       <strong> Description : </strong>    {{$user->description}}<br>
```

and here is my ***AdsController.php***

```
public function show($id)
{
   $user=Ad::find($id);
   
    return view('show',['user'=>$user]);
}
```

What can I do to display even the comments in this page?

Answer (score 0):

Make hasMany relation with comments and retrieve it like this:

```
function getComments() {
  return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'post_id', 'post_id');
}
```

and retrieve all comments use this code:

```
public function show($id)
{
 $user=Ad::where('id', $id)->with('getComments')->first();
 return view('show',['user'=>$user]);
}
```

It will give you all comments along with your post. Please change your pk column and fk column on hasmany function as per your structure.

Comment: sorry  but it doesn't display any think even an error i change my pk column and fk column on hasmany function

Answer (score 0):

If the Ad and comment on the different table you can use query builder to join table, and adding 1 field on comment table calls "ad_id" fo foreignkey.
for example

**Ad Table**
id |name
1 | Ad First
2 | Ad Second

**Comment Table**
id | name | ad_id 
1 | Jon | 1
2 | Doe | 2

**notes :**
you have to set ad_id as foreignkey on comment migration. mayble the code will be like this

```
 Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('project_name');
        $table->integer('ad_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ad_id')->references('id')->on('ads');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and query builder will be like this.

```
$project = DB::table('ads')
                ->join('comments','ads.id','=','comments.ad_id')
                ->where('comments.ad_id','=','ads.id')
                ->first();
```

hopefully can help you